# React Native CheckBox and FlatList: Cannot Toggle, and can only select each item once

Tags: javascript, react-native, checkbox

I am using `import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox';`.

I am only able to '*select*' each '*item*' once and cannot toggle it (change or re-toggle).

*Any help would be appreciated and if there's alternate plugins/packages available feel free to suggest it.*

**Code snippet below:**

```
 import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox';

 export default class FrCreateScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            timeSlots: [
                { id: '1', time: '10am - 11am' },
                { id: '2', time: '11am - 12pm' },
                { id: '3', time: '12pm - 1pm' },
                { id: '4', time: '1pm - 2pm' },
                { id: '5', time: '2pm - 3pm' },
                { id: '6', time: '3pm - 4pm' },
                { id: '7', time: '4pm - 5pm' },
                { id: '8', time: '5pm - 6pm' },
            ],

            //checkBox
            checked: false,
        }
    }

    checkBox(value) {
        this.setState({
            checked: !value,
        })
    }

    getAppointmentTimePage() {
        const { checked, timeSlots } = this.state;

        return (
            <View>
                <Text style={[styles.title, { marginTop: 20 }]}>Select Appointment Time:</Text>
                {<FlatList
                    data={timeSlots}
                    keyExtractor={(times) => times.id}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => {
                        return (
                            <View style={styles.containerTime}>
                                <Text style={styles.textTime}>{item.time}</Text>
                                <CheckBox
                                    value={checked}
                                    onChange={() => this.checkBox(item.id)}
                                />
                            </View>
                        );
                    }}
                />}
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.addContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.addText}>Add Appointment</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                {this.getAppointmentTimePage()}
            </ScrollView>
        )
    };
};
```

[image: Image Screenshot below:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to wrap `FlatList` inside a `ScrollView`. Try below code

```
import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox';

export default class FrCreateScreen extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        timeSlots: [
            { id: '1', time: '10am - 11am' },
            { id: '2', time: '11am - 12pm' },
            { id: '3', time: '12pm - 1pm' },
            { id: '4', time: '1pm - 2pm' },
            { id: '5', time: '2pm - 3pm' },
            { id: '6', time: '3pm - 4pm' },
            { id: '7', time: '4pm - 5pm' },
            { id: '8', time: '5pm - 6pm' },
        ],

        selectedValue: {},
    }
  }

  toggleItem = (itemId) => {
    const { selectedValue } = this.state;
    const isSelected = selectedValue[itemId];
    selectedValue[itemId] = !isSelected;

    this.setState({
      selectedValue: {...selectedValue},
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { timeSlots, selectedValue } = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={[styles.title, { marginTop: 20 }]}>Select Appointment Time:</Text>
        <FlatList
          data={timeSlots}
          keyExtractor={(times) => times.id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            const isSelected = selectedValue[item.id];
              return (
                <View style={styles.containerTime}>
                  <Text style={styles.textTime}>{item.time}</Text>
                  <CheckBox
                    value={isSelected}
                    onChange={() => this.checkBox(item.id)}
                  />
                </View>
              );
          }}
          extraData={[selectedValue]}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.addContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.addText}>Add Appointment</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  };
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

I was struggling with this a lot and you have saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in your code. First, your checked state should be an array. Then, you pass checkbox id in your function, so !value will always be false.

You could try this (I haven’t tried, you probably need to improve it):

```
import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox';

 export default class FrCreateScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            timeSlots: [
                { id: '1', time: '10am - 11am' },
                { id: '2', time: '11am - 12pm' },
                { id: '3', time: '12pm - 1pm' },
                { id: '4', time: '1pm - 2pm' },
                { id: '5', time: '2pm - 3pm' },
                { id: '6', time: '3pm - 4pm' },
                { id: '7', time: '4pm - 5pm' },
                { id: '8', time: '5pm - 6pm' },
            ],

            //checkBox
            checked: [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
        }
    }

    checkBox(index) {
      let checkedCopy = this.state.checked
      checkedCopy[index] = !checkedCopy[index]
        this.setState({
            checked: checkedCopy,
        })
    }

    getAppointmentTimePage() {
        const { checked, timeSlots } = this.state;

        return (
            <View>
                <Text style={[styles.title, { marginTop: 20 }]}>Select Appointment Time:</Text>
                {<FlatList
                    data={timeSlots}
                    keyExtractor={(times) => times.id}
                    renderItem={({ item,  index }) => {
                        return (
                            <View style={styles.containerTime}>
                                <Text style={styles.textTime}>{item.time}</Text>
                                <CheckBox
                                    value={checked[index]}
                                    onChange={() => this.checkBox(index)}
                                />
                            </View>
                        );
                    }}
                />}
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.addContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.addText}>Add Appointment</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                {this.getAppointmentTimePage()}
            </ScrollView>
        )
    };
};
```

Comment: Set is better than array. try below.
checked: new Set('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8')

Comment: @Sylvain, thank you for the suggestion and improvement in code, but unfortunately your code is also showing the same issue that I was facing.

But it's okay, my problem has been solved by the solution provided by Tuan Luong above.